# Why is the Facebook login not asking for correct permissions?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I use Facebook login using `FB.login` (and I don't want to use the Facebook login button). My problem is that after login, the Facebook dialog don't show the listed permission, as follows.

```
FB.login(function (response) {
   if (response.status == "connected") {
      //alert(" connected ");
   }
   else {
       //alert(" not connected ");
   }
}, { scope: 'email' });
```

The Facebook dialog show "**Access my basic information**" only. How do I fix this problem?

**Note:** if I try the Facebook login, it shows the permission correctly.

**Note 2:** the response after the user clicks **Allow** is:

> User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.

Comment: I think they've moved the extra permissions to a secondary screen. Try accepting and see what happens.

Comment: thanks for response, but after accept i get the response

Comment: You using OAuth 2.0? https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because of a mistake in the official documentation.
The property name for the permissions is not "scope", but "perms":

```
FB.login(function (response) {
   if (response.status == "connected") {
      //alert(" connected ");
   }
   else {
       //alert(" not connected ");
   }
}, { perms: 'email' });
```

Comment: thank u very much for your answer,i wasted 2 days, once again thankful to you

Comment: FYI, this is out of date. It seems like Facebook fixed this, and you can now use `scope`. See related question: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6989249/facebook-fb-login-not-requesting-my-permissions

Comment: Was just having an issue with this and email not showing up under the response. Once I changed it to perms it fixed the issue.