# as3 facebook app not asking for requested permissions

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

My facebook app, made in AS3, will not ask for "publish_stream" permission when the auth dialog comes up.

I am using the following:

```
Facebook.login(handleLogin, {scope:'publish_stream'});

private function handleLogin(result:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    if (result)
    {
        trace('login successful');
    }
    else
    {
        trace('login failed');
    }
}
```

The login screen pops up, you can enter your name/password, then the permissions screen comes up, but does not ask for anything.  It just says basic info is being used.  Anyone have any ideas why?  Thanks!

Comment: How do I delete this question.  was working, I just didn;t realize it

Answer (score 1):

I've just read a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711594/why-is-the-facebook-login-not-asking-for-correct-permissions), and the answer was the the documentation has an error - you need to use *perms* not *scope*.
Hope this is the same issue.